# R Programming, how to replicate for districts in a city

Tags: visualization

I am new to R Programming and just learned basics through codeschool.com

Our network spans the city, and it is divided into districts.

I would like to create a map that assigns a value (based on ratio of outdated software and new software) to each district.

This website has sample of 3-D maps that were created by R Programming, and I see one I am very interested in replicating, but for our city only. [image]

[But when I see the source code](http://www.rforscience.com/portfolio/koppen-geiger/), I don't see any mention of latitude or longitude.

My head is spinning, trying to figure out how I will input this, i.e latitude and longitude of a district in our city, versus an assigned ratio, which I believe will be read from a spreadsheet.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latitude and longitude are stored in a [text file](http://www.rforscience.com/wpmain/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Koeppen-Geiger-ASCII.txt) that is read into a table, `Dat`.  It has the form:

```
lat long climate-group
```

For your particular case, you would calculate `Dat[, 3]`.

Comment: What is cls? What does the acronym and values represent?

Comment: `cls` is the column with the [climate zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification).